# how to get bounding box of a scatter plot from axis object in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to get limits of scatter plot objects in an axes. I am trying

```
scplt = plt.scatter([0,12], [-4,3])
ax = plt.gca()
pathcoll = next(filter(lambda x: type(x) is plt.matplotlib.collections.PathCollection, ax.get_children()))

pathcoll.get_clip_box()
```

but it shows nothing similar to `[0,12], [-4,3]`. Any suggestions?

Assume I don't have direct access to `scplt` object.

Comment: What does it show? I guess you just need to transform it...

Comment: Why don't you try using the collection's base type `Collection`. There are so [many](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html) collection types that depend on the marker used in the scatter call that you wont be able to catch all of them without using the base class.

Comment: how would you use `Collection`?  The way it is shipped in the `ax` object is `PathCollection`.

Comment: Changing the filter to `filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,plt.matplotlib.collections.Collection),...`